# I have multiple values(2 different) and how to display values in order?

Tags: mysql

```
if mulitiple values is there like
email
ravi@gmail.com
karthi@gmail.com
ravi@gmail.com
ravi@gmail.com
karthi@gmail.com
karthi@gmail.com

and i want to diplay
ravi@gmail.com
karthi@gmail.com
ravi@gmail.com
karthi@gmail.com
ravi@gmail.com
karthi@gmail.com
```

If two values shuffle in a column. Then i want a result one values and another value.The two values repeated in table.

Comment: What if there are more values like `tim@gmail.com`, `bob@gmail.com`? What is the desired ordering in this case?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more info, please see How to Ask and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to create an intermediate result set like this:

```
SELECT email,
       @seq := IF(@m = email, @seq + 1, 
                   IF(@m := email, 1, 1)) AS seq
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq :=1, @m :='') AS vars
ORDER BY email
```

**Output:**

```
email               seq
------------------------
karthi@gmail.com    1
karthi@gmail.com    2
karthi@gmail.com    3
ravi@gmail.com      1
ravi@gmail.com      2
ravi@gmail.com      3
```

You can now achieve the required ordering in an outer query like this:

```
SELECT email
FROM (
   SELECT email,
          @seq := IF(@m = email, @seq + 1, 
                      IF(@m := email, 1, 1)) AS seq
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq :=1, @m :='') AS vars
   ORDER BY email) AS t
ORDER BY t.seq, email
```

**Output:**

```
email
-----------------
karthi@gmail.com
ravi@gmail.com
karthi@gmail.com
ravi@gmail.com
karthi@gmail.com
ravi@gmail.com
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c420b/4)